# Solve for $x$ (three equations)

Tags: reflection

I've been having trouble with these equations. The three equations have no relation to one and other. I've been trying to solve for $x$:

$$y = 1.15^{x+2}$$

$$y = \frac{1}{1.15^{x+2}}$$

$$y = 1 - \frac{1}{1.15^{x+2}}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a *simultaneous* set of equations? That is, are $x$ and $y$ supposed to satisfy all three equations at once, or are you asking about three different problems?

Comment: Oops, sorry for not clarifying that. No, they are separate equations with no relationship.

Comment: For the first one use log, 
for the second one use log, 
for the third one use log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first, take the $\log$ of both sides, where $\log$ means logarithm to your favourite base, perhaps $e$, perhaps $10$, perhaps $2$. We get
$$\log y=(x+2)\log 1.15.$$
Thus 
$$x+2=\frac{\log y}{\log 1.15},$$
and now solving for $x$ is straightforward.

For the second, take the reciprocal of both sides. We get
$$\frac{1}{y}=1.15^{x+2}.$$
Now use the procedure of the first problem. You may want to use the fact that $\log(1/y)=-\log y$.

Or else you can rewrite as $y=1.15^{-(x+2)}$, and take the logarithm of both sides.

For the third problem, first rewrite as $1-y=\frac{1}{1.15^{x+2}}$.

Comment: Thank you! Your help is appreciated!